# Conditional print in python, without writing an IF for each one of them

Tags: python, if-statement, switch-statement

I write many print(...) lines in the code to verify the middle results.

These are handy when you need them, but when everything works well, I need to commit/delete each one of them. Sometimes I found that I may need them again... then I have to go through each print(...) line again.

So is there a switch, that could activate & deactivate those tmp-print lines? While not influencing other print lines that I always want to activate.

Ps: No one wants to do it with if in each line:

```
if I_want_tmp_print:

   print("one of my 100 tmp print lines")
```

Comment: yes there is, use `logging` instead of `print` statements.

Comment: Just create a function like `def log(msg)`, put IF flag inside of it and instead of `print` use `log`. This way you can enable and disable it using one flag.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html - here's a nice example

Comment: Don't use print statements for debugging your code, use a debugger. Or, use a `logging` framework that allows you to turn on/off the logging from a global place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes if I print enough and I want the debugging 'toggleable' I will write my own function such as:

```
def prnt(string):
   print(string)
   return
```

So then wherever I wan to check my code I will use my function, prnt, instead. And it will display all of the output for me. When I no longer want the output I comment out the print(string) line so nothing is outputted.

If you only want to stop commenting out certain sections of code I will block my code calling a similar function but with a reference number indicating where I have used this in my code.

```
def prnt(string, idx):
   if idx = 1:
      print(string)
   elif idx = 2:
      print(string)
   elif idx = 3:
      print(string)
...
   return
```

So then say I found out that where I was testing in the idx=1 range and I was calling prnt('string to print', 1) was working as I wanted it to, I can just comment out that print line in my function.

Comment: great practice, also works with `prnt("test{}".format(i))`